# Why is LongListSelector selectedItem nothing?

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm not sure if what im attempting to achieve is being done correctly or not.

On a Windows Phone 8 i would like an app to do the following:

Screen 1: display the alphabet in a list (A, B, C, D etc).

Screen 2: When a user selects an item from the list in Screen 1, screen 2 will display the customers whose name begin with that alphabet character (it will contact a web service and get items by the character selected)

Screen 3: Selecting the name from screen 2 would display that customer's details (again it will contact a web service and get details by the name selected)

So i started off by following this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx

This displays the list as expected but when selecting an item, the SelectionChanged event doesn't kick in. Researching around it seems you cant use the LongListSelector to select which alphabet character was clicked. So i used the tap event but the SelectedItem is always nothing.

```
Private Sub LLSAlpha_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs)
    If LLSAlpha Is Nothing Then
        If LLSAlpha.SelectedItem.ToString = "A" Then
            MessageBox.Show("A was selected")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Now i have read somewhere that i have to use the navigateURL method but i cant get the correct event (an event that allows me to target the tapped/selected item) to write that code against?

Am i missing something or should i be using another control to achieve what im attempting to do? Any articles i could refer to? Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

My XAML is

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="LLSAlpha" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="200,200" 
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AlphaTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Listpictures}" 
                                IsGroupingEnabled="True" GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource groupHeaderTemplate}" 
                                JumpListStyle="{StaticResource imageJumpListStyle}"
                                SelectionChanged="LLSAlpha_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: I had some problems when installing the SDK and cannot spend more time on this, that's why I deleted my answer (although it addresses your problem generally, does not provide the specific answer you are looking for). All the .NET-based development are equivalent: create the given control (via "design view") and set up the events as you did. Before accessing any property, make sure that it is not null (IsNot Nothing); in principle, the control (LLSAlpha) shouldn't ever be null; but if this is the case, you should check it too: two different conditions, one for the control...

Comment: If LLSAlpha IsNot Nothing Then and, inside it, one for the given element (before calling any method of it, like ToString):  LLSAlpha.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing. If you are not sure about how to do things, better take codes written in the language you will be using (VB.NET). Bear in mind that event management is different in VB.NET and C#. In principle you shouldn't find any problem to follow the MSDN samples step by step; unfortunately, I cannot test your exact conditions and tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Yes i think in order to install the SDK you need to meet some criteria. Thanks for trying but im sure i have tried what you have advised, even if the LLS selector is not nothing (null) then the selectedItem is always nothing.... Ok i will do a walkthrough of a working VB .Net example and see if that sheds any light.

Comment: In that case your code does not make any sense either: you have to write the code properly (IsNot Nothing at two levels). If the code does not pass through you have to look at what you did wrong (when creating the control, populating it or selecting the items), but you cannot write a senseless code: your statement If LLSAlpha Is Nothing Then does not make any sense: it would trigger an error for sure. If you don't know what you are doing wrong, start doing things right step by step: first step; convert this nonsense into something logical: IsNot Nothing (and repeat this for item).

Comment: PS: just to make the point completely clear. My answer was right: you have to change Is Nothing with IsNot Nothing. But what you want is understanding why you are not able to create a simple Phone App and, although I guess that should be more or less easy by following the MSDN indications, cannot be sure. In summary: correct your Is Nothing because is wrong (no doubt on that) and start looking at other parts to find out why the selectedItem is null; but better do it after changing this condition, in order to avoid an accumulation of errors.

Comment: I agree with what your saying but i have tried a combination of code since it wasnt working. The reason why i left it as it is was after reading that the LLS selector can not be used in this way and must have forgotten about it when i posted. As i say i will go through the walkthroughs to see if i can figure out why i cant capture the SelectedItem which will eventually lead me to correct that code (i usually walkthrough the debugger too which confirms whats going on)

Comment: What is the Type of the items in `LLSAlpha`? Could it be that `ToString()` on such an item will result with an empty value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this resolved. This is the code i used

Now add an ItemTemplates and DataTemplate to the LLS finally add a TextBlock (to display the value)

Then to navigate to another page, have the below code under the SelectionChanged event of the LLS (code converted from C#)

```
If LLS.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
Return

NavigationService.Navigate(New URI("Page.xaml?Item=" & TryCast(LLS.SelectedItem,     CustomerItem).ID, UriKind.Relative))

LLS.SelectedItem = Nothing
End If
```

On the page receiving the Item, under the OnNavigatedTo

```
If DataContext Is Nothing
Dim SelectedIndex as string 

If NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("Item", SelectedIndex)
dim Index as Integer= Cint.Parse(SelectedIndex)

'Do whatever you want here

End If

End If
```